# Problems installing rasterio from conda

Tags: python, rasterio, conda

I'm trying to install the rasterio python package using the conda package manager. But when I try to do this in a new clean conda environment, I get an "Found conflicts!" error with no information on what the conflicts are.

```
conda create --name newenv1 --channel conda-forge rasterio
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: /
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
                                                                                                                       -failed

UnsatisfiableError:
Note that strict channel priority may have removed packages required for satisfiability.
```

I'm wondering whether this has to do with GDAL being previously installed on my computer, although as far as I can tell I have successfully removed it. Otherwise, I have no idea what is causing the problem. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Edit: I was able to successfully install rasterio from the pkgs/main channel, instead of the conda-forge channel that I had been using.

```
conda config --add channel pkgs/main
conda create --name newenv1 rasterio
```

Comment: The first messages for me are just `conda create --name newenv1 --channel conda-forge rasterio
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done`. I would search from the web what could be the problem with current repodata.json. That is probably not a GIS-related problem.

Comment: having the same issue, the solution with pkgs/main worked, thank you. Although the first command is: "conda config --add channelS pkgs/main"